# Can I filter BroadcastReceiver other than using intent filters?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

From what I've understood in the documentation, when i register a BroadcastReceiver using an intent filter in my manifest, the onReceive method will be called.
My application uses DownloadManager to handle file downloads. I want to listen to DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE action. So, in my manifest, I have an intent filter like this:

```
<receiver
       android:name="com.myapp.DownloadReceiver" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My class method is like this:

```
private DownloadManager manager;
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(result));
request.setTitle("MyTitle");
request.setDescription("MyDescription");
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, Test.txt);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

This receiver will receive *all* intents sent by the DownloadManager. Is there a way to restrict the filtering by listening to the completed downloads that were enqueued by my application only? If I try `android:exported="false"` it will not receive DownloadManager broadcasts, as they come from another application.
If I filter the IDs my onReceive method is still called. What i want to achieve is avoiding that my receiver will receive ALL the events.
Thank you!

Comment: `What i want to achieve is avoiding that my receiver will receive ALL the events.` your receiver only is called for download complete events and i think it is a good idea to register your receiver in the manifest because you can process your completed file as soon as possible even though user closed your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not filter broadcasts sent to you by DownloadManager - as long as your receiver is registered you will receive broadcasts for all downloadmanager events.

You can however use id returned by DownLoadManager.enqueue method. In your receiver you can get id of the download that triggered broadcast:

```
Long downLoadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
```

Also I do not recommend to register your receiver in manifest - this will invoke your application on ALL downloadmanager events, you probably dont want that. Instead register your receiver in code after you have enqueued your download and remove it when your download has been finished (successful or not). Also remember to unregister receiver before your activity is destroyed.

If this is not acceptable ie you sometimes want to receive broadcasts when your app is not active you should register your receiver in manifest and switch it on/off as needed.

In your manifest initially disable receiver:

```
<receiver
       android:name="com.myapp.DownloadReceiver" 
       android:enabled="false" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then when you need it - for example after starting a download enable it:

```
PackageManager pm  = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.myapp", ".DownloadReceiver");
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

And when you no longer dont want to receive broadcasts - for example when your download has finished disable receiver:

```
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

This way your application will receive broadcasts only if you need them.

Comment: Okas, I understand what you're saying but maybe there's something wrong. You say that I receive ALL downloadmanager events. You mean that with intent filters in my manifest, I receive only the events i'm filtering from ALL the applications that are using the DownloadManager, right?

Comment: Maybe I should unregister my receiver when my application is being destroied

Comment: You are receiving all DownloadManager broadcasts. You will not receive anything from other applications using DownloadManager. And yes, when you register your receiver in code you should unregister it before your activity is destroyed. Ive edited my answer adding suggestion what to do when you sometimes need to receive broadcasts even when your app is not active.

Comment: I think that I'll manually register/unregister programmatically when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you need an BroadcastReceiver, in your case it should be
`public class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`

You need to override `the onReceive` methode and here is where you receive and handle your broadcast.
In my case for receiving an SMS I checked for

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
```

Sorry if this doesnt fit your needs, I haven't worked with DownloadManager yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I'm asking. I know how to handle receivers. The problem is that I want to avoid receiving intents from other applications that are using DownloadManager. I know that I should look to long ids returned by the enqueue method, but I'm asking if there's a way to avoid triggering of my receiver from other applications using DownloadManager to enqueue and download files.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, DownloadManager does not track and does not care which app started download and all downloaded files are available to all apps.